# Avoid using java.lang.ThreadGroup on Timestamp

Tags: java, thread-safety, timestamp, pmd

My code is coming up as an Avoid Thread Group error when I run a pmd check and I don't see why. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
```

And here is the pmd log:

```
<violation beginline="40" endline="40" begincolumn="36" endcolumn="53" rule="AvoidThreadGroup" ruleset="Basic Rules" package="com" class="Route" externalInfoUrl="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/basic.html#AvoidThreadGroup" priority="3">
Avoid using java.lang.ThreadGroup; it is not thread safe
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I got it to pass the pmd check. I'm not sure why, but I replaced that line with this and it worked:

```
Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
```